# CentOS: e1000 is shown as FIBER port, but it must be MII

Tags: linux, networking, intel

I installed an Intel gigabit card, it is shown as:

```
[root@mail ~]# ethtool eth0
Settings for eth0:
        Supported ports: [ FIBRE ]
        Supported link modes:   1000baseT/Full
        Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
        Advertised link modes:  1000baseT/Full
        Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
        Speed: 1000Mb/s
        Duplex: Full
        Port: FIBRE
        PHYAD: 0
        Transceiver: external
        Auto-negotiation: on
        Supports Wake-on: umbg
        Wake-on: g
        Current message level: 0x00000007 (7)
        Link detected: yes
[root@mail ~]#
```

Thereby I get errors:

```
[root@mail ~]# ifconfig eth0
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:07:E9:0A:75:A5
          inet addr:78.158.192.29  Bcast:78.158.192.127  Mask:255.255.255.128
          inet6 addr: fe80::207:e9ff:fe0a:75a5/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:29351806494030 dropped:4891967749005 overruns:0 frame:19567870996020
          TX packets:0 errors:9783935498010 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:14675903247015
          collisions:4891967749005 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 b)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 b)
          Base address:0xb000 Memory:ff700000-ff720000
```

The other network cards are shown as "MII" and work fine.
Is there any ability to change the port type from FIBER to MII?
ethtool can't change it.

thanks

Comment: Is the machine in question a blade? Why do you want to change the port type?

Comment: No, simple machine. Intel pro gigabit adapter isn't fiber! It must be mii (simple copper cable). But ethtool shows it as FIBER

Comment: Can you tell us exactly which NIC you have?  What is the exact product name or pci id?

Comment: I have removed it from server. But it was Intel Pro 1000/MT PCI.
Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82541PI Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 05). OS: CentOS 2.6.18-164.el5 #1 SMP Thu Sep 3 03:28:30 EDT 2009 x86_64 . If needed, i can install it back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try posting your question to the e1000 developers mailing list, which is actively monitored by the Intel NIC driver developers.  Be sure to include your OS distribution, the output from "ethtool -i eth0", and perhaps the output of lspci.

You can find the mailing list info on the SourceForge site for the Intel NIC drivers:
https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/e1000-devel

Answer (score 0):

When ethtool isn't sure what to say, it just says *something*. In other words, it lies.

Update your kernel to include the latest drivers for your NIC. Then ethtool will know more, and get it right.

Answer (score 0):

Doubt I'll get any answer back after all this time but just wanted to say "me too". I'm getting the same problem as the op back in `2009` with my `8086:1010 Intel Corporation 82546EB Gigabit Ethernet Controller (Copper)` dual port ethernet card and Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS using `e1000` driver:

```
# ethtool eth1
Settings for eth1:
    Supported ports: [ FIBRE ]
    Supported link modes:   1000baseT/Full
    Supported pause frame use: No
    Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
    Supported FEC modes: Not reported
    Advertised link modes:  1000baseT/Full
    Advertised pause frame use: No
    Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
    Advertised FEC modes: Not reported
    Speed: 1000Mb/s
    Duplex: Full
    Auto-negotiation: on
    Port: FIBRE
    PHYAD: 0
    Transceiver: internal
    Supports Wake-on: d
    Wake-on: d
        Current message level: 0x00000007 (7)
                               drv probe link
    Link detected: yes
 
# ethtool eth2
Settings for eth2:
    Supported ports: [ FIBRE ]
    Supported link modes:   1000baseT/Full
    Supported pause frame use: No
    Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
    Supported FEC modes: Not reported
    Advertised link modes:  1000baseT/Full
    Advertised pause frame use: No
    Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
    Advertised FEC modes: Not reported
    Speed: 1000Mb/s
    Duplex: Full
    Auto-negotiation: on
    Port: FIBRE
    PHYAD: 0
    Transceiver: internal
    Supports Wake-on: d
    Wake-on: d
        Current message level: 0x00000007 (7)
                               drv probe link
    Link detected: yes

# ifconfig eth1
eth1: flags=6147<UP,BROADCAST,SLAVE,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether MAC_BOND0  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

# ifconfig eth2
eth2: flags=6147<UP,BROADCAST,SLAVE,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether MAC_BOND0  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

that I have configured in LACP `bond0`:

```
# cat /proc/net/bonding/bond0 
Ethernet Channel Bonding Driver: v5.15.0-69-generic

Bonding Mode: IEEE 802.3ad Dynamic link aggregation
Transmit Hash Policy: layer2+3 (2)
MII Status: down
MII Polling Interval (ms): 100
Up Delay (ms): 100
Down Delay (ms): 100
Peer Notification Delay (ms): 0

802.3ad info
LACP active: on
LACP rate: fast
Min links: 0
Aggregator selection policy (ad_select): stable
System priority: 65535
System MAC address: MAC_BOND0
bond bond0 has no active aggregator

Slave Interface: eth1
MII Status: down
Speed: 1000 Mbps
Duplex: full
Link Failure Count: 0
Permanent HW addr: MAC_ETH1
Slave queue ID: 0
Aggregator ID: 1
Actor Churn State: churned
Partner Churn State: churned
Actor Churned Count: 1
Partner Churned Count: 1
details actor lacp pdu:
    system priority: 65535
    system mac address: MAC_BOND0
    port key: 0
    port priority: 255
    port number: 1
    port state: 71
details partner lacp pdu:
    system priority: 65535
    system mac address: 00:00:00:00:00:00
    oper key: 1
    port priority: 255
    port number: 1
    port state: 1

Slave Interface: eth2
MII Status: down
Speed: 1000 Mbps
Duplex: full
Link Failure Count: 0
Permanent HW addr: MAC_ETH2
Slave queue ID: 0
Aggregator ID: 2
Actor Churn State: churned
Partner Churn State: churned
Actor Churned Count: 1
Partner Churned Count: 1
details actor lacp pdu:
    system priority: 65535
    system mac address: MAC_BOND0
    port key: 0
    port priority: 255
    port number: 2
    port state: 71
details partner lacp pdu:
    system priority: 65535
    system mac address: 00:00:00:00:00:00
    oper key: 1
    port priority: 255
    port number: 1
    port state: 1
```

that is in state `down` of course since both interfaces have `MII Status: down`. The dmesg shows:

```
# dmesg | grep -E "bond0|eth[1|2]"
[   42.999281] e1000 0000:01:0a.0 eth1: (PCI:33MHz:32-bit) MAC_ETH1
[   42.999292] e1000 0000:01:0a.0 eth1: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Connection
[   43.323358] e1000 0000:01:0a.1 eth2: (PCI:33MHz:32-bit) MAC_ETH2
[   43.323366] e1000 0000:01:0a.1 eth2: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Connection
[   65.617020] bonding: bond0 is being created...
[   65.787883] 8021q: adding VLAN 0 to HW filter on device eth1
[   67.790638] 8021q: adding VLAN 0 to HW filter on device eth2
[   70.094511] 8021q: adding VLAN 0 to HW filter on device bond0
[   70.558364] 8021q: adding VLAN 0 to HW filter on device eth1
[   70.558675] bond0: (slave eth1): Enslaving as a backup interface with a down link
[   70.560050] 8021q: adding VLAN 0 to HW filter on device eth2
[   70.560354] bond0: (slave eth2): Enslaving as a backup interface with a down link
```

So both eth1 and eth2 are UP and recognised, `ethtool` says `Link detected: yes` but their links are DOWN. I have the same confusing port type of FIBRE reported by `ethtool` (capabilities reported by `lshw` are `capabilities: pm pcix msi cap_list rom ethernet physical fibre 1000bt-fd autonegotiation`). It is weird and I suspect some hardware or firmware issue. Any ideas are welcome.

P.S: It is not the switch or the switch ports and it is not the cables already tested that.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://serverfault.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://serverfault.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://serverfault.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/548246)